# How to represent big numbers in Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

Elixir is a programming language powered by the Erlang .

> Elixir allows basic types : **integers, floats, booleans, atoms,
>   strings, lists and tuples**

I want to know how to represent big numbers ( say of type **long** ) in elixir. For example 10000000 20000000

Also i want to know how to convert Long numbers to Strings in elixir.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elixir and Erlang integers or of arbitrary size (no differentiation between i32, i64, etc).

```
iex(1)> 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

If you want to convert an integer into a string, it is as simple as calling `Integer.to_string/1`.

```
iex(2)> Integer.to_string(999999999999999999999)
"999999999999999999999"
```

Comment: so this means Integer itself supports operations on big numbers in Elixir ?

Comment: `Kernel.to_string/1` is good enough here, although it could be promilles slower.